# Why is my app-root not 100% height in Angular?

Tags: angular, sass, angular17

It's my first Angular project and I am quite new to web development. I am using Angular 17.0.9.
I want my application to be 100% but the `app-root` tag is always the smallest height possible
[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvnLE.png).

In my `styles.scss` file I have:

```scss
// Global styles
html, body { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body { 
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; 
}
```

I have tried to add to my `app-component.scss` file

```scss
:host {
    height: 100%
}
```

Which doesn't change anything.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a div 100% height of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)

Answer (score 2):

I frequently use

```
:host {
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

on my page/routing components.

About height not growing to 100% [you might look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)

Answer (score 1):

Just add app-root to the global styles

```
// Global styles
html, body, app-root { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```